# SSIS Data Migration for multiple linked tables with identity column

Tags: ssis

My question is related to data migration. I have tons of data in staging tables in SQL and I am working on a task to migrate that data to destination sql server. and destination data model is a bit different from staging.

Here is one example:
In staging database, there is one employer table as follows:
    `| Name   | Mail Address | Mail City | Physical Address | Physical City |
    | ------ | ------------ | --------- | ---------------- | ------------- |
    | Emp1   | 123 Street   | City 1    | 456 Avenue       | City 1        |
    | Emp2   | 999 Street   | City 1    | 456 Avenue       | City 1        |`

And in destination database, there are three tables as follows:

1. Employer (EmpID is identity field)
   `| EmpID | Emp Name |
   |------ | -------- |
   | 1     | Emp1     |
   | 2     | Emp2     |`
2. Address (AddID is identity field)
   `| AddID | AddressLine | Address City |
   | ----- | ----------- | ------------ |
   | 1     | 123 Street  | City 1       |
   | 2     | 456 Avenue  | City 1       |
   | 3     | 999 Street  | City 1       |
   | 4     | 456 Avenue  | City 1       |`
3. EmployerAddressMapping (EmpAddID is identity and AddID and EmpID are foreign keys)
   `| EmpAddID | EmpID | AddID | AddFlag |
   | -------- | ----- | ----- | ------- |
   | 1        | 1     | 1     | M       |
   | 2        | 1     | 2     | P       |
   | 3        | 2     | 3     | M       |
   | 4        | 2     | 4     | P       |`

I want to migrate the data using SSIS. I already migrated employer table by using simple data flow task. But now I am having hard time to migrate rest of the tables due to identity fields and foreign key relations. Specially for the address table where there could be duplicate records for different employers so it is very hard to first insert all the addresses and then manage the linkage by lookup newly inserted addresses.

Is there any way in SSIS to achieve this?

Comment: Yes. First and foremost you need a unique key in your source staging table. The general approach is: 1. Copy data into Employer, preserving the source key from staging in an extra field in Employer (that you'll delete). 2. Copy data into Address, preserving the source key from staging in an extra field in Address. Now you can populate EmployerAddressMapping by doing some tricky lookups. To turn one staging row into two for the Address table you can use a `cross join` in your source. This can be done completely in SQL Script but you can use SSIS if you prefer

Comment: Hi Nick. The problem here is I am not allowed to do any structural changes to the destination database. Is there any alternate way in SSIS to achieve this without doing any table changes? Like is it possible to create all three tables data in single data flow? Something like insert in Employer table and Address table and get the last generated id fields and then insert data in mapping table. Is it possible in one go?

Comment: You need to lookup the identity columns in the destination tables using LOOKUP on the business keys (what determines insert or update of a record)

Comment: Right. Because there is no business key for address table so I guess I need to create one temporary table for Address with a key field and then I can insert Actual address data from that temp table by enabling identity insert and then I can use that temp table's key field to manage my mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

Use two seperate DFT's to load Address Tables. Let the following two be the queries to load them. Ensure that there is a lookup to check respective address are not present before loading into the destination to avoid duplicate  -

```
--Query 1 - Mailing Address
select  distinct 
        [Mail Address]
       ,[Mail City]
from    dbo.Staging; 

--Query 2- Phsyical Address
select  distinct 
       ,[Physical Address]
       ,[Physical City]
from    dbo.Staging;
```

As you are saying Employer's address may be duplicated it is first necessary to populate the Address Table with unique set.

In the third DFT for populating EmployerAddressMapping -

1. Get Employee Name and address from source as part of OLE DB Source as follows -

   select Name 
          ,[Mail Address]
          ,[Mail City]
          ,'M' as 'AddFlag'
   from  dbo.Staging 
   union all
   select Name 
          ,[Physical Address]
          ,[Physical City]
          ,'P' as 'AddFlag'
   from  dbo.Staging;
2. Lookup on Emp table using Emp Name and obtain Emp Id
3. Take the Matched Output and obtain Emp Id. Lookup on Address using address details and get the AddressId.
4. Load the details into the Destination Table with the required field attributes

Of course in addition to this, ensure that your business logic of picking up the delta records are in place.

The one problem I see with this approach is dependency on Emp Name to be unique. If they aren't then you will need to have the source primary key present as part of the Emp table as mentioned by Nick. If they are then it should be okay